# Is there a way to hook into the keyboard menu navigation or selection in React Bootstrap Typeahead?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am using React Bootstrap Typeahead to navigate through an array of tree data. Each tree has an id that I need to access, but I don't want that to be the labelKey.

I've tried tying into onFocus, but the menu items never seem to gain it. onClick works fine, but I need to support keyboard navigation, too. Adding onKeyPress to the menu items doesn't seem to do anything.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<Typeahead
      filterBy={filterByFields}
      id='typeahead-search'
      labelKey={(option) => `${option.scientific_name}`}
      onInputChange={this.startSearch} // fills props.suggestions
      options={this.props.suggestions ? this.props.suggestions : []}
      placeholder="Enter a tree name"
      renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
        <div
          <!--this is the data I need -->
          data-tree-id={option.tree_id} 
          onClick={this.dropdownClickHandler}
        >
          <div>
            <span>
              {option.scientific_name}
            </span>
          </div>
          <small>
            <span>
              {option.common_name}
            </span>
          </small>
        </div>
      )}
    />
```

Comment: When do you need access to the id, and what for?

Comment: I need it for a GET request. As far as when, it could be when the user selected a menu item (enter key) or even when they highlighted the menu item by navigating the menu with the arrow keys.

Comment: A user selecting a menu item triggers the component's `onChange` handler, which will provide the selected item. That item should have the `tree_id` right?

Comment: It does. Typing anything into the search bar also triggers it, but I guess I can add some logic in there to determine whether or not the user has a complete match. Thank you for your help! Once I have a working solution I'll post it as an answer if no one beats me to it.

Comment: Typing into the search bar triggers `onInputChange` and will passes the input value and a change event to the handler, which I don't think provides what you need based on your code. `onChange` seems like the way to go unless there's something I'm not understanding.

Comment: Nice! You're right, I was using onInputChange